# Let $A$ be a set and $R,S$ are relations on $A$. Then....

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, relations

Let $A$ be a set and $R,S$ are relations on $A$. Define the relation $R+S$ on $A$ as $$R+S = (R-S)\cup(S-R)$$
Now show that

1. If $A$ is countable then so does $R+S$
2. Give and example of a set $A$ that is uncountable but $R+S$ is countable.
3. Prove or disprove: If $R$ and $S$ are partial orders on A then so does $R+S$

For the first part, I am thinking that a relation gives us subset of the set on which it is defined, which is in our case $A$ so if $A$ is a countable set then its subset is countable as well.

For the second part, Lets say $A=\mathbb{R}$ relation $S$ gives us rational numbers (or its subset) and $R$ gives us Natural numbers (or its subset) then their symmetric difference which is $R+S$ becomes a countable set however $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable.

For third part, I am thinking of relations $R=S=\{(a,a)|a\in \mathbb{Z} \}$ which holds both reflexive and transitive property but I am not sure about anti symmetry. Also this is just an example. How can we prove (if it is right) or disprove (Give counter example)

Please help

Comment: What is your definition of "relation?" Normally when I see relation without any other adjective I assume it is a binary relation in which case it would not be a subset of $A$ but a subset of $A \times A$

Comment: @PedroAmaral Yes it is a binary relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is not a subset of $A$: it is a subset of $A\times A$. That means that your answer to the second question is wrong from the start: relations on $\Bbb R$ are not subsets of $\Bbb R$. You could, however, let $A=\Bbb R$ and let $R=S$ be any relation on $\Bbb R$, say $\{\langle x,x\rangle:x\in\Bbb R\}$, the identity relation on $\Bbb R$. Then

$$R+S=(R\setminus S)\cup(S\setminus R)=\varnothing\cup\varnothing=\varnothing\,,$$

which is certainly countable.

> If the source of this problem misuses *countable* to mean *countably infinite*, you’ll have to work a little harder. You could, for instance, let $$R=\{\langle n,n+1\rangle:n\in\Bbb N\}$$ and $$S=\{\langle n,n-1\rangle:n\in\Bbb Z\}\,;$$ then $$R+S=(R\setminus S)\cup(S\setminus R)=R\cup S\,,$$ which is countably infinite.

Something very much like your idea, but with a correct understanding of what a relation on $A$ is, can be used to answer the first question. If $A$ is countable, then so is $A\times A$, and therefore so is every subset of $A\times A$, i.e., every relation on $A$.

Your example for the third question will work: your relation is a partial order, and $R+S=R+R=\varnothing$ is not reflexive, so it is not a partial order.

Comment: For the third one if $R+S$ is an empty relation isnt it then partial relation ? I have asked this previously on this site whether empty relations are partial relations or not and the answer was yes.

Comment: @JalilAhmad: It is not a partial order on $\Bbb Z$: a partial order is by definition reflexive (among other requirements). The only set on which $\varnothing$ is a partial order is $\varnothing$.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Could you please also give an example where $R$ and $S$ are not partial order but $R+S$ is partial order

Comment: $R=S=\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ does this works?

Comment: @JalilAhmad: No, that cannot possibly work, because $R+R$ is always the empty set. Here’s a hint for an example: let $A=\Bbb N$, let $R=\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$, and let $S$ be the complement of some familiar partial order on $\Bbb N$.

Comment: Ok from what you said can $S$ be the complement of natural numbers ordered by the standard less-than-or-equal relation

Comment: @JalilAhmad: Yes, that would do just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @JalilAhmad: You’re very welcome.

Comment: By $R=\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ I think you mean $R$ is any relation on $\mathbb{N} right ?

Comment: @JalilAhmad: No, I meant what I wrote: $R$ is the total relation on $\Bbb N$ in which everything is related to everything. That means that for any relation $S$ on $\Bbb N$, $R+S=(\Bbb N\times\Bbb N)setminus $S$, the complement of $S$.

Comment: I think you made a typo here.

Comment: @JalilAhmad: It should read $R+S=(\Bbb N\times\Bbb N)\setminus S$, the complement of $S$.